# How do I install multiple versions of PHP to make .htaccess AddHandler work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, centos

I know a lot of shared hosting services allow you  to use .htaccess  `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php`  to define what php version you want  to use but how to I set this up on a personal CentOS 7 server?

I've tried using Software Collections but I'm not sure what to do once the PHP versions are installed. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.